# GROUP BY with MIN and MAX - Fall within date range of solution

Tags: mysql, group-by, exists

I have the following tables with data:

Table1:

```
id  name    race_type        start_time              end_time
---     ----      ---------        ----------              --------
111 Phelps   Relay       2016-08-20 00:01:00           NULL
111 Phelps   Relay             NULL             2016-08-20 00:02:00
222 Phelps   Relay       2016-08-20 00:03:00           NULL
222 Phelps   Relay             NULL             2016-08-20 00:04:00
333 Lochte  Butterfly    2016-08-20 00:05:00           NULL
333 Lochte  Butterfly          NULL             2016-08-20 00:06:00
444 Lochte  Butterfly    2016-08-20 00:07:00           NULL
444 Lochte    Butterfly          NULL             2016-08-20 00:08:00
```

Table2:

```
name      race_type        current_time       qualifies
----      ---------        ------------       ---------
Phelps      Relay       2016-08-20 00:03:30    
Lochte    Butterfly     2016-08-20 00:05:30
```

For the two transaction in Table2, I need to determine if the CURRENT_TIME for those transactions falls within the START_TIME and END_TIME of Table1 records with respect to each unique ID pairing, name, and race_type.

What I was thinking was to first "merge" the data (id) in Table1 using GROUP BY with MIN and MAX functions:

```
SELECT id,name,race_type, MIN(start_time) AS start_time, MAX(end_time) AS end_time
FROM Table1
GROUP BY id
```

This would give me the following results:

```
+-----+--------+---------------+----------------------+---------------------+
| id  | name   |  race_type    |    start_time        |    end_time         |
+-----+--------+---------------+----------------------+---------------------|
| 111 | phelps |   relay       | 2016-08-20 00:01:00  | 2016-08-20 00:02:00 |
| 222 | phelps |   relay       | 2016-08-20 00:03:00  | 2016-08-20 00:04:00 |
| 333 | lochte |   Butterfly   | 2016-08-20 00:05:00  | 2016-08-20 00:06:00 |
| 444 | lochte |   Butterfly   | 2016-08-20 00:06:00  | 2016-08-20 00:08:00 |
+-----+--------+---------------+----------------------+---------------------+
```

Based on these results I could more easily determine if phelps or lochte current_time for their relay or butterfly swim (in Table2) was in either of the start or end time ranges for their respective name and race_type. If it does fall within one of those ranges, I would set the Table2 qualifies parameter to true.

Could someone recommend a MySQL query that could accomplish this task? I'm guessing I could use some combination of GROUP BY to first "merge" the id's in Table 1, than use `exists`?

Comment: Why do you store `start_time` and `end_time` in different rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `inner join` in order to get all results that the current time falls between the range:

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT id,name,race_type, MIN(start_time) AS start_time, MAX(end_time) AS end_time
FROM Table1
GROUP BY id
) AS results INNER JOIN table2 ON 
  results.name = Table2.name 
  AND results.type = Table2.type 
  AND Table2.current_time BETWEEN results.start_time AND results.end_time;
```

Comment: Based on this solution, how would I additionally set the table2.qualifies parameter to true after the INNER JOIN results are met? E.g. I am looking for an UPDATE and SET qualifies = exists (...) somwehere?  Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why would you like to set it? I dont think you need to save 'calculated' data that will change if the actual data changes. You have a query to get this data, so use it, no need for special column

Answer (score 0):

There are ways to do what you want with two nestet GROUP BY subqueries, but in your case i prefer this one:

```sql
update Table2 t2
set qualifies = exists(
    select 1
    from Table1 t1a
    join Table1 t1b using(name, race_type, id)
    where t1a.name      = t2.name
      and t1a.race_type = t2.race_type
      and t1a.start_time <= t2.current_time
      and t1b.end_time   >= t2.current_time
);
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cf6da/1)